# Is there a way I can alling some "a" tags that are inside some boxes to a logo (vertical-align: middle)

Tags: html, css

I am building my own personal web page, and while doing the "header" I wasn't able to align my "a" tags to the logo... I've been trying everything, but there are no solutions.

This is my code. If I am wrong in some part, please explain me to not commit the same mistake.

HTML

`

```
    <div class="mainBox">
         <!--Logo-->
         <div class="navBox">
            <a href="web.url.com"><img src="Images/Logo3Final.png" alt="logo" id="logo"></a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="navBox">
            <a href="#about">/*About Me*/</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navBox">
            <a href="#contact">/*Contact*/</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navBox">
            <a href="#expertise">/*Expertise*/</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navBox">
            <a href="#projects">/*Projects*/</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`

CSS

```
`#logo{
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 220px;
    right: -100px;
}

 /*MENU*/

.mainBox{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 95%;
    height: 25vh;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}

.navBox{
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20vh;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    background: transparent;
}

.navBox a:hover{
    padding-top: 50%;
    background: transparent;
    color: var(--text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

a:visited, a:active, a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--text-color);
}

.navBox a{
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: var(--text-color);
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    text-align: initial;
}
```

I try changing position values, I tried giving padding-top, top, margin, nesting into antoher div. But I can not achieve what I will like to be.

Here is a ScreenShot of my page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can align .navBox to the center, like this:

```css
.navBox{
    /* ... */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

or you can remove the height you've specified for .navBox which I think is redundant. It will look like this:

```css
#logo{
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 220px;
}
.mainBox{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 95%;
    height: 25vh;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
.navBox{
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBox">
         <!--Logo-->
         <div class="navBox">
            <a href="web.url.com"><img src="https://placekitten.com/96/140" alt="logo" id="logo"></a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="navBox">
            <a href="#about">/*About Me*/</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navBox">
            <a href="#contact">/*Contact*/</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navBox">
            <a href="#expertise">/*Expertise*/</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navBox">
            <a href="#projects">/*Projects*/</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your logo is overflowing its allocated size, as defined by the `.navBox` class.

This is what your header looks like as is:

[image]

This is what it looks like when applying `overflow: hidden` to the navBox class. As you can see, the logo is oversized for its container. You need to limit its height and width OR remove the limitation from the container.

[image]

Removing the height attribute from navBox makes it look like this:

[image]

Looks centered to me.

Comment: Hi, to be honest, this does not fix my problem, I understand what you were trying, but it did not worked. Anyway, thanks for the advice, and how does it work.